# Adding custom engine in Apache Falcon

Tags: apache-falcon

Falcon currently supports 4 engines such as oozie,pig,hive,spark. Is it possible to add another engine ? 
I know i can run my own scripts in oozie. But what I want is to add my own custom engine in apache falcon. 
Can anyone please guide me on this.

Thanks